# И действительно...

Tags: пунктуация

"И(,) действительно, с того самого дня я начал подробно задумываться об этом..."
Нужна ли запятая между "и", "а" и вводными словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно - нет, не нужна. Но вообще от авторского смысла может зависеть.
Если И - усилительная частица, то точно не нужна.
Если же союз, то возможна, хотя тоже далеко не обязвтельна.
Короче, я бы не ставил.

Comment: Спасибо! Наконец-то у меня есть понятное объяснение этому феномену :)